# How do I line up video divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a videos section for my website, similar to the way dribbble.com does it. I would like my video divs to fall into place next to one another like they do on dribbble... I figured creating the videos and floating them inside a larger div would do the trick, but I can't seem to get them to line up right. I know creating three columns would work but that would be kinda redundant.

Can someone give me the basic structure to achieve this kind of behavior?

Comment: `display:inline` and `float:left` is what you need

Comment: Are you trying to create a fluid layout?

Comment: Why not line them up like all other items? Is there anything special about videos?

Answer (score -1):

Using this CSS property I think you will arrange your videos in one line.

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```